# mongodb with zf2 gives an error The class was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: mongodb, zend-framework2

I know I miss something in the configuration.
Can anyone provide the steps for this configuration 
Mongo is running in my terminal properly.
when connect with zend in sequential way it works . but in procedural way it gives error.
this is global config file

```
'driver' => array(
        'odm_default' => array(
            'class'   => 'Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain',
            'drivers' => array()
        )
    ),
```

when I write

```
$dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');

    $user = new User();
    $user->setName("Gembul");

    $dm->persist($user);
```

persist then it gives class not found error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I found this error then I modify my database class means that change the comments in my model class in document section .

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
/**
 * Description of User
 *
 * @author kiwitech
 */
/** @ODM\Document(collection="user") */
class Users 
{

protected $dm;
/** @ODM\Id */
 private $_id;

/** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
 private $_first_name;
/** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
  private $_last_name;
/** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
  private $_login_name;
/** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
private $_email;
/** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
private $tp_id;
/** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
 private $_is_active;
/** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
private $_role_id;

function get_id() {
    return $this->_id;
}

function get_first_name() {
    return $this->_first_name;
}

function get_last_name() {
    return $this->_last_name;
}

function get_login_name() {
    return $this->_login_name;
}

function get_email() {
    return $this->_email;
}

function getTp_id() {
    return $this->tp_id;
}

function get_is_active() {
    return $this->_is_active;
}

function get_role_id() {
    return $this->_role_id;
}

function set_id($_id) {
    $this->_id = $_id;
}

function set_first_name($_first_name) {
    $this->_first_name = $_first_name;
}

function set_last_name($_last_name) {
    $this->_last_name = $_last_name;
}

function set_login_name($_login_name) {
    $this->_login_name = $_login_name;
}

function set_email($_email) {
    $this->_email = $_email;
}

function setTp_id($tp_id) {
    $this->tp_id = $tp_id;
}

function set_is_active($_is_active) {
    $this->_is_active = $_is_active;
}

function set_role_id($_role_id) {
    $this->_role_id = $_role_id;
}

}
```

then I easily solve this bug :)